# 401 access denied from httpclient using Xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am calling an aspx page using https which returns some Request.ServerVariables such as AUTH_USER and AUTH_TYPE. When I call this page through a browser (IE,FireFox,Crome or Safari) all works fine and AUTH_USER correctly returns the callers Userid and AUTH_TYPE correctly return Negoiate as the iis web server is set for Windows authentication using Kerberos. Also when I call the URL using the code below from a C# **Windows Forms** application it also works however when I put exactly the same code into a Xamarin ios app and run on the simulator or ios device I get a "401 access denied due to invalid credentials" and is as if the credentials are not being passed across.

I am using Xamarin 4.0.4.4 in Visual Studio 2015 and have noticed other appends recommend downgrading the level of Xamarin but any help on how to resolve this issue would be much appreciated

```
static async Task<string> DownloadPage1()
{
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        string userid = "xxx";
        string password = "xxx";
        string domain = "xxx";
        string url = @"https://xxx/Default.aspx";
        HttpClientHandler Handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        Handler.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userid,   password, domain);
        using (var client = new HttpClient(Handler))
        {
            using (var r = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url)))
            {
                result = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return result;
            }
        }
     }
     catch (System.Exception Ex)
     {
         throw Ex;
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this thread?   https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42647/problem-with-httpclient-after-updating-xamarin-ios

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did see that one, most appends seem to be saying it is a bug in Xamarin but I can't figure out which version I should downgrade/upgrade to in Visual Studio 2015 currently in Visual Studio help->About it says:

Xamarin   4.0.4.4 (a9c7826)
Xamarin.iOS   9.6.2.2 (be25da5)

but do I need to be using some other version to make this work do you know ?